# I can put my intent into listview

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I have checked that the intent I did pass through my new activity, however, I cant seem to place it into the listview created.

I have derived my listview item, but it is in string. That is the problem I am facing, because i need to convert it into an ArrayList(). So I am kindda unsure whether the last sentence of the code is correct.

```
if (checkedItems != null){ 
 for (int i=0; i<checkedCount; i++) { 
  if (checkedItems.valueAt(i)) { 
   String item = lstMenu.getAdapter().getItem(checkedItems.keyAt(i)).toString();
```

Below is the code for my new class where I am passing through my intent item from previous arraylist. Thanks in advance(:

```
package com.msyd.MenuProject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
public class Result extends Activity {
    ArrayList<String> items;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.result);

        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        String selected = intent.getStringExtra("item"); 
    }

    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        // Configure the listview
        items = new ArrayList<String>();
        ListView lstitems = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.menuResult);

        //lstitems.addItem(selected);
        lstitems.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items));
    }
    private void addItem(String item) {
        items.add(item);
        ListView lstitems = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.menuResult);
        ArrayAdapter<String> ad =(ArrayAdapter<String>)lstitems.getAdapter();  
        ad.notifyDataSetChanged();`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually You need to be bit more clear what you are trying to achieve.
But i think following snippet will help you.

```
package com.msyd.MenuProject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Result extends Activity
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.result);
    }

    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        String selected = intent.getStringExtra("item");
        // Configure the listview
        ListView lstitems = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.menuResult);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        adapter.add(selected);
        lstitems.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Now in future whenever you add new items to adapter dont forget to call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Hey @Vipul I have tried the codes you recommended and my app crashed? Why is that so, the codes you recommended was quite similar to mine. You just shifted some codes into the method and the whole app crashed? Any kind souls able to help?? :|

Comment: You might want to post more information about how the app 'crashed'. Logcat output, stack trace, something more useful.